# Getting timed out (pool is fully used) when using a query from a class

Tags: connection-pooling, sqlconnection

I have a couple of pages in my asp.net (vb) website.
All of the pages need DB so I have created a class and in it I have added the next function:

```
    Public Shared Function query(ByVal sql_str As String) As DataTable

        conn As New SqlConnection()
        conn.ConnectionString = connStringReadOnly
        conn.Open()

        Dim cmd As SqlCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
        cmd.CommandText = sql_str
        Dim ors As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()

        Dim tmp_dt As New DataTable
        tmp_dt.Load(ors)

        ors.Close()
        conn.Close()

        Return tmp_dt

    End Function
```

now, when I use this in my code, I get timed out pretty fast...
I am closing the conn...

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Do you have exceptions? Those would cause the close operation to not execute. Put connection and command into using-blocks, almost always.